# How to prevent asynchronous method form processing?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this problem where, one part of the code process faster than it was meant to.  i some situations when i call client.BeginConnect and it is connected before any other code is treated.

example:

```
client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client); 

// this code below is preformed later because ConnectCallback is called to quickly 

Debug.WriteLine(client.LocalEndPoint.ToString());
```

Problem here is that method ConnectCallback is sometimes performed faster than the code Debug.Writeline(....) 
I only need to block or enable ConnectCallback function so Debug.Writeline  would perform faster than ConnectCallback.

Thanks for help.

Comment: the interesting question is why would you want that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Asynchronous code doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: i want that beacuse some part of the program shouldn't be processed before another. in my example up ConnectCallback shouldn't be processed before Debugg.Write line, so ConnectCallback must wait or something.

Comment: @Bertoncelj1, please see my answer: the `Debug.WriteLine()` should be called right from `ConnectCallback` because it is **callback** (i.e. the operation completed)! =)

Comment: I tried that and it works..... but i still dont know how to prevent 
asynchronous method to  be procesed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great MSDN article: [Using an Asynchronous Client Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8.aspx):

```
private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    try {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
            client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        connectDone.Set();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

So, just move the `Debug.WriteLine()` call into your `ConnectCallback()` method.